# Is there such a thing as a "don't care" when constraining a generic parameter to another generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function that accepts a generic parameter **TD** that I need to constrain to a generic interface.  For example:

```
public T DefinitionPopulate<T, TD>(IDataReader dr)
    where T: class, new()
    where TD: IEntityDefinition<T, Guid>, new()
{
    T t = new T();
    TD td = new TD();
    td.DoInterfaceMethod(t, dr);
    ...
    return t;
}
```

However, we use many different IEntityDefinitions:

```
IEntityDefinition<SomeClass, Guid>
IEntityDefinition<SomeClass, int>
IEntityDefinition<SomeClass, double>
...etc...
```

But my function `DefinitonPopulate` doesn't use the second generic parameter at all, and it doesn't care what it is.  But it does need to handle *all* of the definitions that we have in place, now and in the future.  So it seems that I am stuck creating a new signature for `DefinitionPopulate` for every single IEntityDefinition second generic parameter that we have in place...   *unless...*

**Question**: Is there some way that I can tell the compiler that I don't care what the second type parameter is?  Something like a wildcard?

**EDIT**: I have accepted the answer that I did because it is the true answer to the question that I asked.  However, **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17482166/50356)** provides an excellent solution and is what I ended up using to resolve the underlying issue that I was having - make sure you check it out!

Comment: I think you are overusing generics just too much. You should think about redoing your design so they use less generics. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: You will be speaking differently, when you have methods and classes that have 5 generic parameters (that you need type out) and no way to refactor it properly.

Comment: Actually, the example I gave was simplified from the 5-parameter *real* class that we have in our application.  So your suggestion is to write multiple classes for every version of the class we have instead of using generics??

Comment: I'm suggesting complete redesign. Something like visitor pattern might be better than tons of generics. But I don't know that unless I see the whole problem. But that might be too much for SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot instantiate a generic type without specifying all the type parameters.

Probably the best you can do is to add that unused type parameter of the interface to your generic type paramaters:

```
public T DefinitionPopulate<T, TD, DontCare>(IDataReader dr)
    where T: class, new()
    where TD: IEntityDefinition<T, DontCare>, new()
```

This allows you not to care when writing the generic code, but naturally any specialisations will need to supply that type.

Comment: Yup - as I suspected...  Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 9):

I believe, in this case, you should have an `IEntityDefinition<SomeClass>` interface that all those inherit from, that is:

```
 interface IEntityDefinition<T>
 {
    void DoInterfaceMethod(T, DataReader);
 }
```

And then have the rest of the generics inherit from there:

```
 interface IEntityDefinition<T, TD> : IEntityDefinition<T>
 {
    // blablaba
 }
```

If you can't change that, you could add a third type parameter to your function generic, but that's bad design, I'd say.

Comment: Yeah - as you may suspect, this code is in *heavy* use throughout our large internal application.  Can't be changed, unfortunately.  Seems the third parameter is the way to go.

Comment: It's always like that... however I still believe that's going against the `interface` rules... interfaces should be the least common denominator, if you are not using that second type at all in some implementation that actually uses the interface, probably the interface is not well designed.

That said, yes, I understand how it can not be changed when it's widespread across a large application (I myself have many problems like that on my own old applications :-) ).

Comment: Btw, changing the interface  *should* not hurt your existing implementation... all existing classes would implement both the parent and the child interface so it's just a definition change (Which you can use for new code).

Comment: Yup - it's not a matter of how hard it is technically-speaking, but a matter of convincing the hoarde of project managers (not to mention the other programmers) that we should make a sweeping change to something that has been in place for years, just to support my one little function.

Comment: @MichaelBray: Changing an interface so that it inherits from another interface moving some of its members to that other interface would require that all code which implements or uses that interface be recompiled, but should not require any changes beyond that.  Is the usage of the interface spread among so many *different* applications that such a change would be problematical?

Comment: @supercat: No..  And as it turns out, I *was* able to convince the team to make this change.  So that eliminated my need for the DontCare type in the accepted answer.  However, I don't expect to switch the expected answer because even though this is the solution I ended up at, the currently accepted answer is the one that truly answers the question I asked.   I will edit the question to point people here though.

Answer (score 3):

No wildcards - you'll have to add a third generic parameter to your definition, purely to allow the flexibility:

```
public T DefinitionPopulate<T, TD,TOther>(IDataReader dr)
    where T: class, new()
    where TD: IEntityDefinition<T, TOther>, new()
```

Comment: Yup - I started to go down that path, then thought "wouldn't it be nice if..." but alas.. no love.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI both you and David gave essentially the same answer, but I had to give him the check because his answer showed up first (by seconds).  I did +1 you tho.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own post for future readers after a colleague pointed out something that is close.  My original question had to do with generic type parameters on methods, but if you are trying to specify a default for a class, then there is a "sort of" answer - inheritance.

To be clear, this isn't strictly a "default".  It is more similar to overloading methods and then calling the most specific version, but like method overloading, it essentially achieves the same result.

For example:

```
public class Parent<T1, T2>() { ... }
public class Parent<T1> : Parent<T1, int> { ... }
```

in essence defaults the T2 parameter to an `int`.  Maybe not appropriate in all cases, but if your case is simple this might be a good workaround.

Comment: If you are not using that `int` at all, I'd have to insist that this is an **EXTREMELY HORRIBLE** way of programming (I think so even of the accepted solution on this question) and if I was on charge of any programmer that did this, he'd probably get a good telling-off out of this.

Comment: Thanks...  Clearly your solution is the better answer to the problem I was *having* (I've now noted this in the question), but the accepted answer is the one that actually answers the question I *asked*.  Congratulations on seeing the real issue.  However, to your point, would you care to clarify why you think *this* technique is so horrible?  It's not that the `int` isn't being used, it's just that we are providing an option where the programmer doesn't have to specify `T2` all the time.  How is this any different than providing a default value for a method parameter?

Comment: It's my oppinion (and just my oppinion) that code should not be made "comfortable", but "good". Adding a type parameter which is not used at all is just bad code (again, IMHO), which leads to possible misunderstandings in the future (I can see a bachelor in the near future reading upon that code and spending hours trying to figure out why there was an `int` type parameter which was not used). I'd think the same about adding a default value for a parameter which is unused: if it's unused, just _do not add that parameter_, don't make a default value for it.

Comment: _PS: btw, I was not expecting you to change the answer, I was just specifying my oppinion on the answer... sorry if it sounded otherwise_